# R Project Import Error

Tags: r, import, project

I'm brand new to R Project. 
I've tried to import using the file path, and no matter what path way I use I get this same error. It says the  back slash and the first character after it is an unrecognized escape.

I can import files by using the file.choose() function and manually navigating to my file, but I need to be able to use the  file path method in code so that I can run multiple iterative steps without having to be there to choose the file at every point.

Does anyone have any ideals on why this error might occur? Is there anything wrong with my code? Is there some kind of configuration I need to do?

Thanks.

> Data1 <- read.table(file="\Head-Location-001\MarketingAnalysis\Competitive Intelligence\Stick Rate\Last week\Test.cvs" sep",", header=TRUE)

Error: '\C' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\fknp-sfs-001\fknmktanlys\

[Import Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iny5c.png)

Comment: Try using ordinary slashes (/) instead of the backslashes in the path. Or use double backlashes at each occurrence.

Comment: I went and tried different combinations of slashes and now it's giving me: "Error: unexpected symbol... "

Comment: I think you're missing a comma and an equal sign before the separator: `, sep= ","`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace all the `\` with `\\`.

it's trying to escape the next character in this case the C so to insert a `\` you need to insert an escaped `\` which is `\\`

or

Replacing them with `/` works as well